# How to type LaTeX in Wordpress efficiently

Tags: packages

I have some problems when use $\LaTeX$ code in Wordpress as the following:

1. I use Mathtype (or any math editions which have option translate to LaTeX code), but that LaTeX code can't be used in wordpress.
2. I also use Jetpack package for my wordpress blog, it has the structure:

> $latex < latex code here >$

I find this way of represent LaTeX in Wordpress is annoying. So I want to ask

*Is there any software can transform Latex code easily to Wordpress fastly and correctly?*

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Sorry, your question off-topic since WordPress does use MathJaX etc. but not LaTeX really. You can use `[latex]E=mc^2[/latex]` or the QuickLaTeX plugin, for example

Comment: Yes there is [latex2wp](https://lucatrevisan.wordpress.com/latex-to-wordpress/).